# Grant OAuth permission to Google Sheets for deploying an Apps Script using Python API

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-oauth

I have been using the Google API from Python to create an Apps Script with a Google Sheet as its parent. Within the Apps Script, I am writing data to the parent sheet. However, when I try to deploy the Apps Script using the API, I consistently receive the error "Requested entity was not found."

I have noticed that when I manually deploy the Apps Script from the web interface, I first need to grant OAuth permission to the script to access the Google Sheets. After granting permission, I am able to deploy the script successfully from the API code as well.

```
# Import required libraries
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

# Define your credentials
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('path/to/credentials.json')
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments'
]

# Build the API service
service = build('script', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
def create_script(sheet_id):
    # Create a new Apps Script project
    request = service.projects().create(
        body={
            'title': 'My App Script',
            'parentId': sheet_id
        }
    )
    response = request.execute()
    script_id = response['scriptId']
    script_code=     '''function addRowToSheet() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var newRowData = ['Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3'];  
    sheet.appendRow(newRowData);
    }'''
    request = {
        'files': [
            {
                'name': 'Code',
                'type': 'SERVER_JS',
                'source': script_code
            },
            {
                'name': 'appsscript',
                'type': 'JSON',
                'source': {}.strip()
            }
        ]
    }
    create_file_request = service.projects().updateContent(
        scriptId=script_id,
        body=request
    ).execute()
    return script_id 
def deploy_script(script_id ):
    # Deploy the Apps Script
    request = service.projects().deployments().create(
        scriptId=script_id ,  # Replace with the ID of your Apps Script
        body={
            'scriptId': script_id,
            'versionNumber': 1,
            'manifestFileName': 'appsscript'
        }
    )
    response = request.execute()
    deployment_id = response['deploymentId']
```

My question is, how can I grant the required OAuth permission directly from the API code? I have access to a token with the necessary permission, or alternatively, how can I prompt the user to authenticate with their Google account to grant the permission to the project?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you can't oauth2 requires that a user grant consent by clicking on the consent screen

Comment: how can i pop him that screen from the python code?

Comment: only way I know is to create a web app using flask but I'm not sure about mixing that with app script